# how to disable default number input validation when set a min and max

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, input, react-hook-form

I have an InputController like this :

```
import React from "react";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";

import { Input } from "./input.component";
import { InputControllerProps } from "./input.interface";

export const InputController: React.FC<InputControllerProps> = ({
  name,
  control,
  rules,
  defaultValue,
  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      rules={rules}
      defaultValue={defaultValue || ""}
      render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value }, fieldState: { invalid, error } }) => (
        <Input
          {...props}
          id={name}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            onChange(text);
            if (props?.onChangeText) props.onChangeText(text)
          }}
          errorMessage={invalid ? (error as any).message : ""}
          invalid={invalid}
          value={value ?? defaultValue ?? ""}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

in a component I use InputController like this and specify min and max and rules :

```
 <InputController
                control={control}
                name="importance"
                label="اهمیت سوال"
                requiredInput
                type="number"
                rules={impactValidation}
                min={1}
                max={5}
                defaultValue={data ? data?.importance : 1}
                formClassName="w-6/12"
              />
```

and impactValidation is :

```
const impactValidation = {
  required: "لطفا میزان اهمیت را وارد نمایید.",
  min: {
    value: 1,
    message: "حداقل میزان اهمیت ۱ می باشد."
  },
  max: {
      value: 5,
      message: "حداکثر میزان اهمیت ۵ می باشد."
  },
  pattern: {
    value: /^-?[1-5]$|^0$/,
    message: "لطفا فقط اعداد صحیح بین یک تا پنچ را وارد کنید.",
  },
}
```

but now when use enter a number above 5 instead of my custom error mssg i got the default version of html. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Might be this issue is related to the regular expression pattern used in the impactValidation. The pattern you provided (/^-?[1-5]$|^0$/) seems to only allow numbers from -5 to 5 and zero. To allow numbers from 1 to 5 and reject other numbers, you need to update your regular expression.

```
const impactValidation = {
  required: "your message...",
  min: {
    value: 1,
    message: "your message..."
  },
  max: {
    value: 5,
    message: "your messsage..."
  },
  pattern: {
    value: /^[1-5]$/, // here's the updated regular expression to match numbers 1 to 5 only
    message: "your message...", 
  },
};
```